# Need to summarize data from multiple excel worksheets onto one summary page

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm trying to create a yearly summary for some of our transfers. Essentially, I have 12 sheets, one for each month of the year, and each entry is given one of four specific "Transfer Rationales" in column L. I need to be able to create a worksheet that gives me a running year-to-date summary based on each transfer rationale.

So say, for example, the transfer rationale I'm looking at is called "Incorrectly Assigned" - I think need to have the summary page show columns G-K of each row where column L is "Incorrectly Assigned" from all twelve month sheets.

I've been looking at VBA code and trying to tweak some to work, but I could use some help!

EDIT:

Obviously it's not working as I need or I wouldn't be here, but I don't have much knowledge about VBA. I have something here where the code is grabbing the entries where column L met the criteria, but it was

a) copying all the columns, and I only need G-K to paste, and

b) was putting the copied rows all in one row in the summary tab, so I could see the data for a split second, and then it would overwrite with the next line and so on until it finally settled on the last entry found.

SECOND EDIT:

So I have a code that now (mostly) works, I've pasted it below and deleted the old code above.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim WkSht As Worksheet
     Dim r As Integer
     Dim i As Integer
     i = 1
     For Each WkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
      i = i + 1
             If WkSht.Name <> "Incorrectly Assigned" Then
                     For r = 1 To 1000

                     If WkSht.Range("L" & r).Value = Sheets("Incorrectly Assigned").Range("A1").Value Then
                             WkSht.Range("E:L").Rows(r & ":" & r).Copy
                             Sheets("Incorrectly Assigned").Range("E:L").End(xlUp).Offset(i, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                     End If
                     Next r
             End If
     Next WkSht
End Sub
```

The problem now is that it is only grabbing the last match from each worksheet - so say January has four matching entries, it's only pasting the fourth entry, then the next row down it'll paste the last entry from February etc. and then if there's an entry in say November that matches, it'll be pasted in the 11th row from the beginning, rather than each entry being pasted one after another.

Comment: Can you show the code you've been using so far and explain what is not working on those?

Comment: I've been trying a bunch of different things that I've found from googling over the last couple of days - I will try and relocate the code that worked best, and will post it here with the errors that were occurring.

Comment: @EWit I posted the code in the original question, and explained the problems I'm having with it.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need VBA - just refence the cell in the other tab:

```
SheetName!CellAddress
```

> Precede the cell address with the worksheet name, and follow it with an exclamation point.

If you need VBA, then I have understood your question incorrectly.

EDIT:

Lets start with problem B:

> was putting the copied rows all in one row in the summary tab

Lets look at the code you use to paste values:

```
Sheets("Summary").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Here you always paste everyting in the same place, in cell A65536 which you offset by one. On every iteration of your loop, the values will be at the same place. Change the Offset(1) to

```
Offset(0, r)
```

Now on every iteration you will paste on a different row, because r will be 1, 2, ..., 1000. See MSDN for documentation on [Offset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060%28v=office.15%29.aspx). Select a values that accomplished a paste the way you need.

Lets go to the next question:

> a) it was copying all the columns

I will edit once the first part works as it should for you.

Comment: I might not have been totally clear ... so if there are say 300 entries in each worksheet, and only a portion of them have "Incorrectly Assigned" as the transfer rationale, I need the code to search all sheets, locate the rows where column L = "Incorrectly Assigned", and then paste columns G-K of only those rows into the summary tab.

Comment: @Becky McPhee This can be done with an excel `if` statement while referencing a range on an other page. I would avoid VBA as long as posssible, its always an upkeep hazard. However, I will try to give a VBA answer later if no one beats me to it.

Comment: I posted the VBA code I have so far and the problems with it in the original question

Comment: I've updated the code in my original post with what I have now that's working, and the problems with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Better to create a sub-routine that you call from your "CommandButton1". Then you can call the procedure from more than one location. You can also generalize it by using an input parameter 'transferID' which defines the summary you want.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call PrintSummary("Incorrectly Assigned")
End Sub
```

It will likely need some tweaking to get it how you want, but this should give you some ideas to get you started:

```
Sub PrintSummary(transferID As String)

    Dim ws      As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim wso     As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim lrow    As Long
    Dim rng     As Excel.Range
    Dim rngo    As Excel.Range
    Dim cell    As Excel.Range
    Dim colH    As Variant
    Dim i       As Integer

    '// Define columns for output
    colH = Array("G", "H", "I", "J", "K")

    '// Check for summary sheet (for output)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wso = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If wso Is Nothing Then

        '// Summary worksheet does not exist :/
        Exit Sub

    Else '// format worksheet for output

        '// for example...
        wso.Cells.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Set rngo = wso.Range("A1") '// define output start
        Set wso = Nothing

    End If

    '// Loop through worksheets
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        '// Check for valid worksheet name
        Select Case VBA.UCase(ws.Name)

            Case "JAN", "FEB" '// and so forth...

                Set rng = ws.Range("L1")
                Set rng = ws.Range(rng, ws.Cells(Rows.Count, rng.Column).End(xlUp))

                For Each cell In rng

                    If (VBA.UCase(cell.Text) = VBA.UCase(transferID)) Then

                        '// Print meta data
                        rngo.Offset(lrow, 0).Value = ws.Name
                        rngo.Offset(lrow, 1).Value = transferID

                        '// Print values
                        For i = 0 To UBound(colH)

                            rngo.Offset(lrow, i + 2).Value = ws.Cells(cell.Row, VBA.CStr(colH(i))).Value

                        Next i

                        '// Update counter
                        lrow = lrow + 1

                    End If

                Next cell

            Case Else

                '// Not a month? do nothing

        End Select

    Next ws

End Sub
```